# Weird Transition Behaviour in IE10 Metro Mode Only

Tags: jquery, css, transform, transition, internet-explorer-10

I've written the following that handles animation for a lightbox event:

```
obj.css({
 'transition':'transform 0.2s linear 0s',
 'transform':'perspective(1000px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) translate(0px,0px) translateZ(0px)',
 'transform-style':'preserve-3d'
});
```

to keep it simple I've stripped out the variables and vendor prefixes. 
This code works 100% across all devices I've tested, and performs the animations smoothly.

However, there's an odd problem I've encountered in IE10. When in Metro Mode only (Desktop mode IE10 works perfectly), the animation will jump... then perform the animation ... then jump again when it's finished. The jump is subtle, probably about a 20-30px shift. I'm just curious if anyone else has experienced any transition differences in IE10 between Metro Mode and desktop mode or any other differences between the 2 that might help explain this shift?

No errors in the code, and the console is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen IE10 do weird things if you apply a transition and a transformation at the same time, to debug you can try...

```
obj.css({'transition':'transform 0.2s linear 0s'})

setTimeout(function(){
  obj.css({
   'transform':'perspective(1000px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) translate(0px,0px) translateZ(0px)',
   'transform-style':'preserve-3d'
  });
}, 10);
```

If this doesn't work you can try starting with default values...

```
obj.css({
 'transition':'transform 0.2s linear 0s',
 'transform':'perspective(1000px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotate(0) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) translate(0px,0px) translateZ(0px)'
})

setTimeout(function(){
  obj.css({
   'transform':'perspective(1000px) rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0deg) rotate(10deg) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) translate(0px,0px) translateZ(0px)',
   'transform-style':'preserve-3d'
  });
}, 10);
```

This code is horrid, of course, it's just meant to let you discover where the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with it a bit. IE10 has been working great, but I'm only noticing the issue in Metro Mode.

Comment: thanks for the effort but I'm still experiencing the problem in IE10 Metro Mode. What you've written above is actually similar to how I'm running the code. The transition and transform are working well together - but only in IE10 desktop mode :p hopefully something will come up. Thanks!